# padding-bottom css bug in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding

Firstly I'd like to say I'm kinda new to webdesign so forgive me if I just opened up a useless thread.

That said,

I think I kinda could've possibly discovered a weird bug in Bootstrap: while trying to create a very simple header for a website I'm building I noticed that adding `padding: 10px;` to the CSS would return in difference to the left and top paddings, but none on the bottom one, thus resulting in text being totally off-sided to the bottom.

The behavior of this being, IMO, that Bootstrap is calculating bottom paddings starting from the top of the div, not from the bottom.

So to give 10px padding to a 100px tall div, one should give `padding-bottom: 110px;` which feels kinda weird honestly.

Here is a little demonstration/verification example I made using both Bootply and JSFiddle. Both try to have `height: 100px; padding-bottom: 70px;` on the div, doesn't work on Bootstrap

with Bootstrap: http://www.bootply.com/mUYldKGmKE

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fqj65yy/

how to fix it on Bootstrap: `height: 100px; padding-bottom: 170px;`
(I can't post more than 2 links)

tried with both Chrome and Firefox.

Tell me what you think, if this is true or not, and in case I just typed something stupid please close the thread and erase this from your memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap css includes the following code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This includes padding (and other box properties) in the element's total width and height.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ujosu13t/1/

Learn more here: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Thanks a lot that behavior was really confusing me  now I know a little more

Answer (score 0):

I think it's true to use this snippet because i have try this code
`padding-bottom: 170px;` instead of `padding-bottom: 70px;`

Bootstrap doesn't add the pixels for padding-bottom but it replace it

Here is my Example

```css
.black {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 170px; /* instead of padding-bottom: 70px;*/
    color: #ab5469;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="black">
  Something to say
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I tried to say and how i solved it, I was only asking why it is :)

Comment: Normal CSS add The padding to The widht/height but Bootstrap use The bigger size For Example: height: 50px , padding: 20px (Bootstrap use height); height: 50px, padding :70px (Bootstrap use padding)